# How to Filter Data within Date Range with Searched Data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, filter

I have fetched data within date range.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31')";
```

Its working well shows data between dates but when I search perticular data within date range it is showing all matched records outside date range.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31') AND ID LIKE '%dhaval%' OR firstname LIKE '%dhaval%' OR lastname LIKE '%dhaval%' ";
```

Above query searches all data named dhaval in entire table.

I want searched data within date range how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know how to use brackets.
1st part is before `AND` and 2nd is after

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31') 
      AND (ID LIKE '%dhaval%' OR firstname LIKE '%dhaval%' OR lastname LIKE '%dhaval%') ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have parentheses in your condition, but in the wrong place.  You would seem to want:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' AND
      (ID LIKE '%dhaval%' OR firstname LIKE '%dhaval%' OR lastname LIKE '%dhaval%')
```

You need to learn about `AND` and `OR` and the precedence of operations.  They work in a manner similar to arithmetic operators.  So, `1 + 2 * 3` is `6` and not `9`, because it is parsed as `1 + (2*3)`.  In SQL Statements, `OR` is like `+` and `AND` is like `*`.